# Google Calendar API request is denied for scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

My app needs to create a Google Calendar and manage events in it for users. Google API Console allows to create a consent form for this scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created

It is supposed to allow creation of secondary calendars and events in those calendars. Description reads:

> Make secondary Google calendars, and see, create, change, and delete
> events on them

However, after a user gives permission through the consent form etc, I am getting PERMISSION_DENIED when I try to create a calendar (I am using the REST api https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

My code and the rest of the plumbing (authorization code, access token etc) works because if I use this scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

I am able to create the calendar.

So, anybody knows if https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created is deprecated or something? It is not listed in the V3 calendar documentation but I was hopping that it continue to work. I hate to ask the user for full permission to all calendars since I only want to create and access a secondary calendar and that scope supposed to do exactly what I need.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created might not seem as valid scope - but works for me.
Successfully could create new calendar with that scope, then manage events within it, and calendar itself appears on list of calendars in calendar.google.com

Can't really help much without knowing exactly the flow you have on creating and executing requests to google. Also keep in mind it worked for me with server side app. Using latest library provided by google for PHP.

Comment: As of Aug 16, 2023, I can confirm this answer, so the accepted answer is not true. These undocumented scopes do appear when you enable the API on the google cloud console and work as described. It seems like Google needs to update the OAuth scope part and include  "calendar.app.created" scope there.

Answer (score 1):

- As you can see under [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar), https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created  is not a valid scope for Calendar API v3.
- The documentation for [Calendars:insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) states that the only valid scope for creating a new calendar is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
- You notice yourself that if you try to create a calendar with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created - be it on OAuth2 playground or elsewhere - the request fails with a 403 error

CONCLUSION

**Unfortunately https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created is not a valid scope, the acceptance of this scope on [OAuth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is a bug.**

Comment: The scope works fine, it just seems that the documentation is lacking. With this scope I am able to create a new calendar, and then manage the events on THAT calendar. I can't list other calendars or manage other calendars. You need to store the calendar ID of the calendar that you create, and then direct the rest of the API operations to that specific calendar.

Comment: Google's documentation of these scopes is known to be incomplete. Google is aware of it but has not fixed it. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229997305#comment7