# Permission Denied when using /calendar.app.created in Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

Good morning,

We are using the scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created

> Make secondary Google calendars, and see, create, change, and delete events on them

We are getting PERMISSION_DENIED when we try to create a calendar

Is anyone familiar with any issue in calendar.app.created? Does calendar.app.created usually work?

Please note that we cannot use the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar because it is a Restricted Scope, and we need to use the non-sensitive scope calendar.app.created.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the API documentation on [Calendars: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/insert):

> Creates a secondary calendar. Try it now or see an example.

The scope used there is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`

**Update from comment for visualization**

> I understand that but the calendar.app is deprecated. You can see the available scopes for calendar on [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar). These are the valid scopes to use in Calendar API V3
>
> You can also check this other question where it is stated that it is not a valid scope: [Google Calendar API request is denied for scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474688/google-calendar-api-request-is-denied-for-scope-https-www-googleapis-com-auth)

Comment: Thank you Kessy however we cannot use auth/calendar which is a restricted scope, we are looking to instead use /auth/calendar.app which is a non-sensitive scope.

Comment: I understand that but the `calendar.app` is deprecated. You can see the available scopes for calendar on [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar). You can also check this other question where it is stated that it is not a valid scope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474688/google-calendar-api-request-is-denied-for-scope-https-www-googleapis-com-auth